# No titles or contents in answer list on profile page, only “View Answer”

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, profile-page

The “Answers” list on the profile page displays no titles or contents anymore, only “View answer.” This happens on all sites, here is an example from Stack Overflow:

[image: screenshot of answers page in user profile]

Comment: We're aware of this and it's impacting a few different things. We're looking into a fix! Updates soon! Thanks for letting us know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The “Answers” list on the profile page displays no titles or contents anymore

- If you want a **summary of the contents** you should use search, e.g: [`user:me is:a`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:me+is:a)
- The bug in the User Profile has been fixed; the answers and questions listing is displaying **titles**, as seen in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of answers page in user profile]